# PHP converting (integer) returns to strings

Tags: php

This is something weird that started happening recently.

```
function someFunction() {
    return 0;
}
if (someFunction() == 0)
    runCode();
elseif (someFunction() == '0')
    runOtherCode();
```

In this situation runCode() will not be called but instead runOtherCode() will be called. Any reason why this is happening?

Edit: Using === fixed this error in some situations. However the other time this issue was present was when returning integer results from a database. For some reason the integers where being converted into strings but adding (int) to the data before returning the data fixed that error.

Comment: Even it were true that the result of `someFunction` is converted to string, it wouldn't matter. You are comparing using `==` which does not check the type and thus `'0' == 0` evaluates to true (`'0' === 0` however does not).

Comment: For us to be more helpful it may be handy to post your actual code here. Unless this is, of course, your actual code.

Comment: something is wrong elsewhere, check this demo http://3v4l.org/tsDPj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use strict comparison to prevent type coercion. Basically like this:

```
if(someFunction() === 0) 
elseif(someFunction() === '0')
```

3 equal signs instead of two invokes a strict comparison and is the only way to differentiate between string and integer comparison.

Edit:
This is also relevant in other cases, so always consider it.

Comment: Using loose comparison `== 0` should still evaluate to true though, in OP's question.

Comment: Ahh. Wow. It seemed like that was obviously the problem, since that evaluation doesn't really make sense does it? I ran his version of the code and it works just fine. It still may have to do with strict comparisons, if he didn't post the exact code, but thought this was an equivalent example.

Comment: Yeah my initial thinking too ;) That's why I asked OP for his actual code, because I feel that there may be more to it.

Comment: This solved half my problem. The other half was integers from my database where being converted to strings for some reason. Now I just have to convert them back before returning.

Comment: Is your database column set to int or var? If the column always accepts integers, you should always make it an int column if possible, because it's processed faster (I'm talking about sql, but assume this is the case in pretty much all databases).

Comment: It's set to int which is why I don't understand why it gets converted to a string.

Comment: That is weird. How are you accessing the data from the sql database? Just mysqli_fetch_assoc()?

Comment: Actually now that I think about it recently switched from fetch_assoc to fetch_object and now I keep running into this problem. I'll have to do some testing to see if it's the root of the problem.

Comment: Nope just switched to fetch_assoc and still integers are being converted to strings.

Comment: Pretty weird. Without seeing everything it'd be hard to figure out the problem, which you obviously can't show everything. I guess for now, the best solution is str_replace("'", '', $result);